# How to capture a picture in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, camera

python newbie here I have following code  which I'm using to capture a picture using opencv. It captures the picture when I press **q** key on keyboard.
Working fine so far.

```
import cv2


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

    cv2.imshow('frame', rgb)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        out = cv2.imwrite('capture.jpg', frame)
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I need it to capture the picture when I give a command (like 'Capture now'). Can anyone help me how to capture a frame when user gives the written command rather than by pressing the key. Thanks

Comment: How is the user going to write commands without touching a key?

Comment: Do you want to give `Capture now` command from the terminal?

Comment: @Akhilesh yes! for example I write the code `command= input('Enter command')`
And when I type 'Capture pic' and press enter, it should capture the pic.

Comment: @MarkSetchell my question was 'to capture image using command rather than by pressing the key'. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can write like

```
reqCommand = 'Capture_pic'
command = input('Enter command')
if command == reqCommand:
    out = cv2.imwrite('capture.jpg', frame)
```

Update:

This update is to make it enable to not block the execution of the program

```
import cv2
import threading

command = None

def process():
    while True:
        command = input('Enter command')

thread = threading.Thread(target=process)
thread.start()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
reqCommand = 'Capture_pic'
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

    cv2.imshow('frame', rgb)
    if command == reqCommand:
        out = cv2.imwrite('capture.jpg', frame)
        thread.terminate()
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This is a blocking call which will stop reading and displaying new frames until user has enters a command.

Comment: @Zindarod... Thanks to inform, I have changed the code accordingly.